# Pass value to view when create

Tags: sencha-touch

I want to pass arguments self-defined to a view when creating it at the app level, but it doesn't work. I have read the class system in sencha documentation, and relevent problems in Stack Overflow, but that hasn't helped to resolve my issue.

```
 Ext.define('ImgPanel', {
 extend: 'Ext.Panel',
 config: {
    flex: 5,
    appName: '', // self-defined 
     },
```

> ```
>   var imgPanel = Ext.create('ImgPanel', {appName: 'city'});
>   alert(imgPanel.getAppName());   // does not show the 'city' that I'm expected
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `className`, use a [string dot-namespaced format](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext-method-define). Instead of,

```
Ext.define('ImgPanel', { //...
```

Change the class name to include the application's (`Ext.application`) name,

```
Ext.define('MyAppName.ImgPanel',  { //...
```

[Check out this working example.](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#U9wBJ)